# Font Size and Style Testing of App in iPhone and Android

Tags: android, ios, iphone, apk

How would we able to test Font Size and Style of an App in iPhone and Android. Font for text in App NOT browser. In simple browser you just inspect element and check the font. How to do it for An APP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a bit unsure as to what you are asking so let me clarify. Are you asking,"How do I identify a font an app is using?" Or are you asking,"How do I test out various font specifics for an app?"

Comment: How can I inspect elements on native iOS application

Answer (score 0):

```
 style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
```

try this in android for the same style as ios.  set TextAppearance as per requirement as small, medium ,large.

Comment: shivanshu thanks for replying. Though i quite didnt get it. How would i able  to check font for an app

Comment: anytime ,,, u got the solution ?

Comment: if u set  the text by TextAppearance tag in xml then it set the font as well as style as per the standerd format. and u can do the same for  ios too.